# Android Studio / React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning ReactNative and trying to install/configure Android Studio. I got the following issue: under [*Configure*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo7YM.png), the check boxes are [greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jwxi.png). Please check the screenshots. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need API less than 26 only of you don't need an emulator. By the way which Android Studio are you using?